# How to connect google compute engine to domain?

Tags: django, dns, hosting, google-compute-engine

I have a GCE instance and Django project served on localhost of this VM.
Also I have a domain name at dot.tk.
How can I connect them so my Django project will be availible not on localhost, but on my site on .tk domain?
I read some articles, but still don't understand.

Comment: You need to assign a static external IP to your VM. Then linking a domain name to an external IP has nothing to do with GCE. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/configure-instance-ip-addresses#assign_new_instance